# Diagrams in SVG versus HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I want to start a project where I need to draw diagrams consisting of rounded rectangles connected with lines and a JavaScript action when I click some elements. This needs to work in all modern browsers.

Both SVG and HTML5 Canvas seem to be able to do this so I wonder what would be best.

Also I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so if there are libraries that do such things I would like to know; I took a look at Raphaël and some other JavaScript drawing libraries but they don't give all the functionality I need. In Google's API there is such a tool but it is very limited.

Comment: What kind of diagrams? How large exactly? What kind of functionality are you looking for that libraries don't have right now?

Comment: the size should be adjustable, the diagram is for a genealogy program

Comment: If I were you I would go with svg, and build it with something like backbone.js, this way you can just create templates for your objects and have interaction still.

Comment: @RGB: any example of backbone with such a diagram ? I will use Ruby Sinatra as the server which has routing, i believe backbone also does routing, so how to combine ?

Comment: +1 for Ruby, +1 for Sinatra. You're on the right track, friend! :)

Comment: they would each have their own level of routing, Sinatra would be on client side, and in backbone, it would be client side..you can use them independently of each other, or not at all on..the only thing is that you will have to intercept the render() and make sure that the nodes are built as svgElements and not htmlElements

Comment: I have this https://github.com/raddrick/svgb/ which hasnt had an update in a while...but thats basically whats going on..

Comment: Peter, I've been working on a powerful diagramming library for Canvas with a large set of features (nodes/links/groups/layouts/undo manager/templates/data binding/etc). If that sounds like something that would interest you please email me (see profile) and I will give you a link to the private alpha.

Comment: Simon: i will, but are you suggesting Canvas is better for this ? I saw some SVG answers of you and would think you should be on the SVG side ?

Comment: Phrogz: thanks but now you make me wonder, can you realy at some level give multiple upvotes ?

Comment: @peter Perhaps the gods can, but I certainly can't :)

Comment: Would you edit your post to explain what specifically is missing from Raphaël and Google's API that you need? It might be that one or both of these would do what you want, but you've just not found how to do so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use SVG because—as a *retained-mode* drawing API—you can attach event listeners directly to specific elements, and change properties of specific elements and have the page magically update. Further, as a vector-based format, it is resolution-independent.

HTML5 Canvas, by comparison, is a `non-retained-mode` (aka *immediate-mode*) drawing API; every pixel you draw is blended with all other pixels on the canvas, with no concept of the original shape. Further, as a raster-based format, you would need to do some extra work to get the drawing commands to adjust for different display sizes.

**In general, you should use Canvas if and only if you need:**

1. Direct setting of pixels (e.g. blurs, sparkly effects), or
2. Direct getting of pixels (e.g. reading a user's drawing to save as a PNG, [sampling portions of the image to detect visual overlaps](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_shape_edge_arrows.html)), or
3. **massive** number of 'objects' that won't move much or track individual events (SVG can be slow to redraw with thousands of objects).

Note also that you don't have to choose only one or the other. You can draw SVG onto canvas. You can include bitmaps (images) in SVG. You can even include HTML5 Canvas in SVG via `<foreignElement>`. You can have a single HTML page with multiple layered canvases and SVG elements with transparent backgrounds, intermingling the output of each.

Comment: thanks Phrogz, but i'm not sure if the interaction will permit me to eg add a node with connectors and see the result withour refresh or  doing a round trip to the server to regenerate my entire SVG..

Comment: @peter JavaScript can modify the SVG DOM on the fly, adding manipulating, and removing nodes (just like in HTML). The web browser automatically redraws the view as appropriate (just like in HTML). In canvas, by contrast, "moving" an item requires clearing and re-issuing all drawing commands. This is not "hard" with a library that maintains virtual objects for you. See my edit.

Comment: @peter, phrogz is right on, you can manipulate svg just like you can manipulate html with javascript...also why you can use backbone.js! :)

Comment: @Phrogz One more advantage to using Canvas is that it performs better on most versions of IE. There's no SVG support in the older ones, and what little there is these days is not very fast, definitely not comparable with Chrome or even FF, especially where large numbers of textual objects are involved.

Comment: @Quran - I have found the performance of SVG on legacy IE (in the form of VML) perfectly serviceable, even for animation.