# Does d3.js support dynamic Sunbursts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I would like to create a mashup of the functionalities as seen from

http://bl.ocks.org/4063423 and http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Sunburst/example2.html

I would like to use d3.js or at least a pure javascript solution but a solution that will respond to mouse clicks to display more information about the selected section.

Zooming in and out is not mandatory, but if I can achieve it, it will be good.

Now my question, Is there a framework that can support this or do I have to mash them up on my own.

Disclaimer: google was not that helpful!

Comment: It will be possible within D3. Every element in the D3 sunburst is an SVG path which can be assigned click events like any other DOM element. Later (1.6+ I think?) versions of jQuery can do so as if the SVG element was a div. I believe there's an easier way using D3 itself - check the docs. The other example looks to be [HTML5 canvas not SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10321946/568458) (or could be SVG drawn on canvas?), so I'd hit the D3 docs and build something that toggles divs of data from each SVG path rather than trying to merge the two.

Comment: What do you mean by _zooming_ exactly? Just scaling in to see the smaller elements or a hierarchical zooming like: http://bl.ocks.org/4348373 ?

Comment: @musically_ut Zooming is scaling in and out to see the elements details as can be seen here: http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do with D3 alone: http://bl.ocks.org/4678148 If you click any element, the element will be *focused* and transitioned to 90 deg with the `selected` class set on it.

Also, the legend text on the top right changes to the name of the element selected. The part of code which achieves this coupling is:

```js
d3.selectAll("path").on("click", function (d, i) {
  var newAngle = - (d.x + d.dx / 2);

  innerG
    .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("transform", "rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * newAngle) + ")");

  // Set the class "selected" on the chosen element.
  path
    .classed("selected", function (x) { return d.name == x.name; });

  // Update the text box with the right context
  // This can be arbitrarily complex to show as many details about the
  // object as required.
  textBox.data(["Clicked: " + d.name])
      .text(String);
});
```

---

**Update**

For the zoomable behavior such that the clicked element transitions to the center, you can use almost the same code as used as [here](http://bl.ocks.org/4348373) or [here](http://bl.ocks.org/4348373). I have made small changes to the code to show how to extract information about which item was clicked: http://bl.ocks.org/4747342

The change in code required is simpler than before:

```js
d3.selectAll("path").on("click", function (d, i) {  

  // Zooming
  path.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));

  // Update the text box with the right context
  // This can be arbitrarily complex to show as many details about the
  // object as required.
  textBox.data(["Clicked: " + d.name])
      .text(String);
});
```

Comment: I thought it was easy, but didn't think it was that easy! Cold feet I guess, plus I am newbie in d3.js, not that I am making excuses ;( Thanks.